# ffmpeg .iff image sequence to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a file sequence of format test2#.iff, and i want to convert this sequence to a video, i have tried following commands:

```
ffmpeg -f IFF -r 25 -start_number 75 -i "test2%d.iff" -vcodec libx264 test2.mp4
Error: test2%d.iff: No such file or directory

ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -start_number 75 -i "test2%d.iff" -vcodec libx264 test2.mp4
Error: [image2 @ 00000000002ee220] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none): unspecified size Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options test2%d.iff: could not find codec parameters
```

I also have tried various codecs but it gives me same errors, can any of you please shed some light on what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you have a sample file? Have you tried specifying dimensions for the input files with `-s:v 640x480` or similar? Please include the full, uncut console output as well.

Comment: Hi, i found the problem, ffmpeg does not support .iff format sequence, i tried with png and jpg it seems to work fine. Thanks anyways :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that ffmpeg does not support .iff format sequence, i tried with png and jpg it seems to work fine.